# Run SoapUI request multiple times with different input

Tags: soap, soapui

I need to run the same SOAP request 57 times, changing only one XML tag value for each run.

Is there a way to write something like

```
<Foo>$MyDinamicValue</Foo>
```

in my request and set the value of $MyDinamicValue from a list of values that I have defined somewhere?

I have SoapUI 5.4.0, free version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may employ groovy script to achieve the same.

Comment: With the licensed version, you get data-driven tests out of the box, which matches exactly what you want.  However, the free version does not.  This has been asked on SO loads of times.  Try searching for 'SoapUI data driven test' and you'll find lots of different ways to achieving this.  Even Smartbear's own site has a solution (https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Data-Driven-Testing-in-Soapui-Free-version/td-p/125076) posted by the man @Rao himself.